# When was the term "fantasy" first used to describe the genre?

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre

The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction was first published  in 1949 (under the title The Magazine of Fantasy no less). Does it mean that the fantasy was recognized as a distinct genre at the time already and that the word was used as the name of the genre? Or was it established later under the influence of such magazines? In short, what's the first recorded use of it as a genre?

Comment: The word "fantasy" was used in magazine titles as early as 1931: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=pub_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=fantasy&C=AND&USE_2=pub_ctype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=MAGAZINE&USE_3=pub_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=pub_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=pub_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=pub_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=pub_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=pub_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=pub_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=pub_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=pub_year&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Publication

Comment: The Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction is a good resource for this kind of question: https://sfdictionary.com/view/1013/fantasy

Comment: @user14111, it shows "For performance reasons, Advanced Searches are currently restricted to registered users.". Anyway, can we be sure that the term was used to refer to the recognized and distinct genre?

Comment: If Arthurian Legend is seen as fantasy, it could go as far back as the 12th century

Comment: Sorry about that. Here is a archive.org scan so you can judge for yourself: https://archive.org/details/miracle-v-01-n-01-1931-04-05  I'm not sure difinition of the "recognized and distinct genre" may have changed over time; in 1931 it was probably broader than "Tolkienesque quest adventure with elves, dwarves, wizards and orcs.".

Comment: @A.Steer I may be wrong, but I thought the OP was asking about the use of the term "fantasy" rather than the genre itself.

Comment: If people at the time of the Arthurian legends saw them as fantastical, would that then be the start of a genre, even if those people didn't understand that? I think this question will be hard to answer anyway

Comment: @A.Steer, an indication of the recognition of it as a genre could probably be inferred from the creation of a library/publishing classification or from works on literary theory.

Comment: @user14111, thanks for the sfdictionary link, so it could be argued that in 1932 already science fiction was seen as a subgenre of fantasy, which would imply that the genre of fantasy itself was recognized.

Comment: It might be worth checking out the term "romance" as it applied in the past. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_(prose_fiction)  At some point most prose that we would call fantasy (also science fiction) today would have been called romance.  It seems like you are looking for the point when this changed.  Also, my perception, which I can't back up, is that book shops and publishers were primary drivers of the genrefication of fiction.  "Fiction" became "SF & Fantasy", "Horror", "Romance", etc.  Then SF & Fantasy were split.  Then those were further divided in to sub-genres.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_fantasy says "It was not until 1923 that the term "fantasist" was used to describe a writer (in this case, Oscar Wilde) who wrote fantasy fiction. The name "fantasy" was not developed until later; as late as J.R.R. Tolkien's The Hobbit, the term "fairy tale" was still being used."

Comment: @PM2Ring, good find, from the same page "Literary critics of the era began to take an interest in "fantasy" as a genre of writing, and also to argue that it was a genre worthy of serious consideration. Herbert Read devoted a chapter of his book English Prose Style (1928) to discussing "Fantasy" as an aspect of literature…". Need to comb through the sources, but we are close I think.

Answer (score 2):

Use of the term "fantasy" (spelled "phantasie" at the time) for individual works goes back at least to Elizabethan times. The OED cites  *1542–3 Act 34–5 Hen. VIII, c. 1 Balades, plaies, rimes, songes, and other phantasies*.

I don't know what criteria would be used to say that a grouping of such individual works becomes a "genre".  A noteworthy example might be the collection "*Essays and Phantasies*" by James Thomson (1881).  This one is even listed in the Science Fiction Encyclopedia, since (news to me!) some of Thomson's work can apparently be considered as steampunk.

Comment: I'm not sure if it counts as a use in the sense of a literary genre. As I mentioned in the comments, it seems to me that a use of the term in discussion of classification of literary works would undoubtedly mean recognition of it as a distinct category. I hope someone more knowledgeable in literary theory can enlighten us on this matter.

Comment: The notion that there is some finite [fixed?] list of literary genres seems odd to me outside the context of the publishing industry.  The OED definition of "genre" is  "A particular style or category of works of art; esp. a type of literary work characterized by a particular form, style, or purpose".  If the question is specifically about publishing practice, fair enough.  In general usage, however, I think you can pick any characteristic you like and the refer to "works of that genre".